# How to work around needing to update a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, runtime-error

I need to delete a k/v pair from a dictionary in a loop.  After getting `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration` I pickled the dictionary after deleting the k/v and in one of the outer loops I try to reopen the newly pickled/updated dictionary.  However, as many of you will probably know-I get the same error-I think when it reaches the top of the loop.  I do not use my dictionary in the outermost loop.

So my question is-does anyone know how to get around this problem?  I want to delete a k/V pair from a dictionary and use that resized dictionary on the next iteration of the loop.

to focus the problem and use the solution from Cygil

```
list=[27,29,23,30,3,5,40]
testDict={}
for x in range(25):
    tempDict={}
    tempDict['xsquared']=x*x
    tempDict['xinverse']=1.0/(x+1.0)
    testDict[(x,x+1)]=tempDict

for item in list:
    print 'the Dictionary now has',len(testDict.keys()), ' keys'
    for key in testDict.keys():
        if key[0]==item:

        del testDict[key]
```

I am doing this because I have to have some research assistants compare some observations from two data sets that could not be matched because of name variants.  The idea is to throw up a name from one data set (say set A) and then based on a key match find all the names attached to that key in the other dataset (set B).  One a match has been identified I don't want to show the value from B again to speed things up for them.  Because there are 6,000 observations I also don't want them to have to start at the beginning of A each time they get back to work.  However, I can fix that by letting them chose to enter the last key from A they worked with.  But I really need to reduce B once the match has been identified

Comment: Can you post the original code? That would help way more than an ambiguous description

Comment: Okay I posted the code-I have some data that needs to be matched by hand. If I can delete a k/v once I have used it then I can reduce the amount of work I have to do by hand.

Comment: Double check the code formatting.  Linef 4 is clearly off, and since python uses indenting for denoting blocks, its hard to tell if the code displayed above would actually do what you intend it to do.

Comment: @PyNEwbie You didn't post the *original* code I asked for, but your *current* using pickle. Additionally, please at least try to isolate the code that's causing the problem. See http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html for details.

Comment: The only difference in the code are the pickle lines.  Trust me that the problem is I try to modify the dictionary.  That is my question.  You don't want to untangle my code.  I am an academic researcher and trying to process data, not a computer guy

Comment: @PyNEwbie Exactly, I don't want to untangle your code. That's why I'm neither interested in raw_input nor pickle nor the names of your keys. And I'm confused about the difference between "academic researcher" and "computer guy". The point is I want *less* application-specific code, not *more*.

Comment: Just a sidenote: The second test of len(tempDict) is never true and redundant because if len(tempDict) were 0, the code three lines above would have called break. Also, the very last break is a syntax error. If its intention was to break an outer loop, it should be written as a test at the beginning

Comment: Well I was struggling to make things work and I got lost in the loops.  The script works as intended as long as I don't delete. I keep meaning to take a programming class.

Comment: @PyNEwbie Way better :D. Just a problem, stackoverflow indentation should be done automatically (copy your code, select it, and press Ctrl+K). I tried to correct it, can you check it?

Comment: phihag- not sure what you mean here I tried to correct it, can you check it?  Thanks for your patience

Comment: @PyNEwbie I wasn't sure if the second for did belong to top-level or in the first for. As I wrote, code in stackoverflow is tricky, please check it afterwards. But, as I infer from your latest edit, I was right. I *rollbacked* it - don't want to start an edit war, but the latest addition isn't valid

Comment: I am still confused-sorry I just copied the code from IDLE-it worked in idle and the second iteration better illustrates the problem so I am going to try again. feel free to edit

Comment: Okay now I see what you were referring to.  It should work now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without code, I'm assuming you're writing something like:

```
for key in dict:
    if check_condition(dict[key]):
       del dict[key]
```

If so, you can write

```
for key in list(dict.keys()):
    if key in dict and check_condition(dict[key]):
        del dict[key]
```

`list(dict.keys())` returns a copy of the keys, not a view, which makes it possible to delete from the dictionary (you are iterating through a copy of the keys, not the keys in the dictionary itself, in this case.)

Comment: Am I right in assuming since I need to test\review values that I can't do this because I have to access dict[key]['someValue']

Comment: for key in dict.keys() *does* return a view in py3+. Use list(dict.keys()) instead.

Comment: cygil: I made some significant edits, please rollback and complain to me if you don't like them

Comment: Hi Philhag, it's cool.  Obviously I've been lazy and need to bone up on all the new aspects of Python 3.

Answer (score 4):

Delete all keys whose value is > 15:

```
for k in mydict.keys(): # makes a list of the keys and iterate
                        # over the list, not over the dict.
    if mydict[k] > 15:
        del mydict[k]
```

Comment: If you want to be absolutely sure, use `mydict.keys()[:]` to copy the list of keys.

Comment: @S.Lott: mydict.keys() already generates a list with a copy of keys on python 2.x

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
for ansSeries in notmatched:
```

To:

```
for ansSeries in notmatched.copy():
```